# trying to understand this instruction in context w. Segment registers

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb

I am trying to understand this instruction:

```
 0x80496fa <yellow_preflight+18>:     mov    eax,ds:0x804c220
```

and these are the register values at runtime:

```
  EAX: 0x000000D2  EBX: 0xB7FB6FF4  ECX: 0xBFFFF438  EDX: 0xBFFFF3A4  o d I t S z A P c 
  ESI: 0x00000000  EDI: 0x00000000  EBP: 0xBFFFF468  ESP: 0xBFFFF450  EIP: 0x080496FF
  CS: 0073  DS: 007B  ES: 007B  FS: 0000  GS: 0033  SS: 007B
```

So for my understanding if this was just a regular mov instruction w/o the 
'ds:' prefix in the source address. Then eax should hold the '0x0804c220'
Value. But when i step further in the execution the value of eax becomes

```
EAX: 0xB7FB7440
```

instead of the expected value. So i am trying to find a explanation for this behavior. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is x86 assembly, right?

Comment: @ScottHunter jap that right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ds:` is a so called **segment override prefix**.

For example, let's say you write down this in your source code (NASM syntax):

```
mov eax, [0x804c220]
```

You did not use a segment prefix, but the assembler will use the default segment for this kind of memory access, the `ds` (data segment). It will transform your code to this on its own:

```
 mov eax, [ds:0x804c220]
```

That is why using the `ds:` prefix in the source code would make no difference in your example. But when you use a different segment overwrite prefix, it will make a difference. For example in this case the assembler will use the `fs` instead of default `ds` segment:

```
 mov eax, [fs:0x804c220]
```

Answer (score 0):

`ds:0x804c220` is an address; the instruction is moving the value at that address into `eax`.

Comment: lol thanks *g*. But that means the ds: prefix has no effect at all to the address? Then why you would write code like that and not simply skip the 'ds:' prefix?